# NFS root filesystem doesn't mount at boot

Tags: boot, nfs, root-filesystem, u-boot

This is an embedded device with a custom kernel (see below for relevant config).  It's an x86-32 machine booting like this: coreboot->uboot->linux.  I can mount the NFS share in linux if I use on-board storage for the rootfs.  I'm pretty sure that linux is correctly autoconfiguring the network at boot using `ip=dhcp` (note: this is using the network's DHCP server; it's just handing out IP addresses, and has nothing to do with BOOTP or anything like that).  I've also tried explicitly setting parameters with `ip=`, results are the same as for `ip=dhcp`.

Here's what gets executed in uboot:

```
set ethaddr 02:00:00:10:00:43; set serverip 204.54.80.195; set ipaddr 204.54.80.37
set bootargs rootwait raid=noautodetect rw console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=$serverip:/yukon ip=dhcp
ext4load mmc 0 ${kernel_addr} ${kernel_path} ; ext4load mmc 0 ${initrd_addr} ${initrd_path} ; zboot ${kernel_addr} 0 ${initrd_addr}
```

Here's the network coming up in linux:

```
Sending DHCP requests ., OK
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 204.54.80.10, my address is 204.54.80.37
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, hwaddr=02:00:00:10:00:43, ipaddr=204.54.80.37, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=204.54.80.1
     host=204.54.80.37, domain=jdnet.deere.com, nis-domain=(none)
     bootserver=0.0.0.0, rootserver=204.54.80.195, rootpath=
     nameserver0=204.54.84.14, nameserver1=164.121.15.220
```

Linux panics when it can't mount the rootfs:

```
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
VFS: Cannot open root device "nfs" or unknown-block(2,0): error -6
```

Relevant kernel config:

```
root@localhost:~# zgrep -E NFS\|IP_PNP /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_IP_PNP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_BOOTP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_RARP=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V2=y
CONFIG_NFS_DEF_FILE_IO_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL is not set
CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
# CONFIG_NFS_SWAP is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_V4_1 is not set
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
# CONFIG_NFS_USE_LEGACY_DNS is not set
CONFIG_NFS_USE_KERNEL_DNS=y
# CONFIG_NFSD is not set
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
```

NFS can be mounted in linux with

```
mount.nfs 204.54.80.195:/yukon /mnt
```

I'm probably missing something obvious.  I'm looking for ideas and common mistakes.

---

Updates:

- The nfsrootdebug kernel parameter doesn't have any effect.
- Though there is an initrd, it is not used.  It is definitely not necessary for booting with on-board storage.  All the necessary drivers are compiled into the kernel, not as modules.

---

Aside: I have determined that using ethernet in uboot makes it unusable in linux; that's another bug for me to solve, but I can avoid using the network in uboot so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Are you sure the device name is `root=/dev/nfs`? I would suspect that this where the problem is.

Comment: @Jeight That's how you tell linux to use NFS as the rootfs. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt

Comment: I'm not sure then. Maybe it has something to do with this:                 rdinit=<executable file>

  To specify which file contains the program that starts system
  initialization, administrators can use this command line parameter.
  The default value of this parameter is "/init".  If the specified
  file exists and the kernel can execute it, root filesystem related
  kernel command line parameters, including `nfsroot=', are ignored.

Comment: But I don't specify `rdinit=`, and if I did, where would it live (in the initrd, I'd guess).  There actually isn't any initrd, I will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was really close.  I needed to enable no_root_squash in /etc/exports:

```
/srv/nfs       204.54.0.0/16(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)
/srv/nfs/yukon 204.54.0.0/16(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)
```

And although both `mount.nfs $serverip:/yukon /mnt` and `mount.nfs $serverip:/srv/nfs/yukon /mnt` worked, I needed the full path for the Linux cmdline:

```
console=ttyS0,115200 rootwait rw nfsroot=$serverip:/srv/nfs/yukon ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs
```

Comment: For your use case that's probably OK, but others should know "no_root_squash" is generally considered a security risk. See:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Securing_NFS-Do_Not_Use_the_no_root_squash_Option.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check /etc/exports, /etc/hosts.deny, /etc/hosts.allow on the server to see if dhcp-allocated address (204.54.80.37) is allowed.

Comment: I can mount the nfs rootfs once I'm in Linux, using the same hostname:/path as I'm giving the kernel in the cmdline.